# How do I auto-increment subsets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subset, auto-increment

Consider a MWE with a table with four columns: ORDER_BASIS, GROUP_1, GROUP_2 and ORDER_VALUE.  The first three are populated with data and I would like to now populate ORDER_VALUE with an integer (starting with 1 for each subset) that indicates the order of the ORDER_BASIS value for a given combination of GROUP_1 and GROUP_2.  For example:

| ORDER_BASIS | GROUP_1 | GROUP_2 | ORDER_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | A | X | NULL |
| 2.4 | A | X | NULL |
| 7.3 | A | X | NULL |
| 2.1 | B | X | NULL |
| 3.4 | B | X | NULL |
| 7.1 | A | Y | NULL |
| 8.4 | A | Y | NULL |
| 9.6 | A | Y | NULL |

should become:

| ORDER_BASIS | GROUP_1 | GROUP_2 | ORDER_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | A | X | 1 |
| 2.4 | A | X | 2 |
| 7.3 | A | X | 3 |
| 2.1 | B | X | 1 |
| 3.4 | B | X | 2 |
| 7.1 | A | Y | 1 |
| 8.4 | A | Y | 2 |
| 9.6 | A | Y | 3 |

Comment: Whats a MWE????

Comment: Minimal Working Example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `SSMS` means you are using SQL Server, you can apply a *row_number* window function here in a derived table (or CTE) and directly update it:

```
update t set Order_Value = rn 
from (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by group_1, group_2 order by order_basis) rn
    from t
    where Order_Value is null
)t;
```